# How can I minimize my Splunk search function if all of the host names begin with the same letters?

Tags: splunk

I have a number of hosts (servers) and I want to search through all of them except for 4 different ones.

Here is what I have working at the moment to exclude the 4 servers:

```
(host!="ajl2dal8" OR host!="ajl2dal9" OR host!="ajl2atl8" OR host!="ajl2atl9")
```

While this works fine, its fairly sizable and will only get longer if I need to exclude more. Since they all begin with ajl2 and have either atl or dal and a number, is there any way I could get something like this to work:

```
(host!="ajl2[atl|dal][1|2|3|4]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search command (which is implied before the first pipe) does not support regular expressions.  You can use wildcards, however, as in `(host!="ajl2*")`.  You can use regular expressions after the first pipe with the `where` or `regex` commands.

```
... | where NOT match(host, "ajl2[atl|dal][1|2|3|4]") | ...

... | regex host!="ajl2[atl|dal][1|2|3|4]" | ...
```